# What is .gst file

Tags: ios

[image]

I found it in my IOS project.

I'll be grateful if someone can tell me what is it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever tried googling this ?

Comment: you can refer to this link https://fileinfo.com/extension/gst

Answer (score 0):

From what I found online:

> Map format used by MapInfo MapX and MapXtreme mapping software;
>   contains a visual map and data about locations within the mapped area;
>   may include extra layers, such as rasterized images placed on the map.

### What it is

https://fileinfo.com/extension/gst

### On how to open it

https://file.org/extension/gst